# LINQ selecting a table to query at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, linq

I'm new to LINQ and trying to write a query which chooses the table to query based on a variable entered at runtime. The basic idea is that I have a Contacts table for each person in a Persons table. I can get all the data I want from the entities but I can't find the other table when I query. Here's the code;

```
    public void GetFriendsList(string username, Person[] people)
    {     
        string table = "FL." + username;

        DataTable friends = new DataTable(table);

            var filePaths =
            from row in friends.AsEnumerable()
            select row.Field<string>("Friend's Name");

        var friendsArray = filePaths.ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < people.Length; i++)
        {
            people[i] = GetPerson(friendsArray[i]);
        }     
    }
```

I've also tried doing this with something like the following at the top but VS isn't recognizing the FillDataSet function.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
FillDataSet(ds);

DataTable products = ds.Tables[table];
```

Any advice appreciated, sorry for the vagueness. I'm assuming I'm missing a connection string or something. I've stepped through this the and code clearly isn't connecting to the table.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using Linq2Sql or Entity Framework or anything that would actually connect to a database? FillDataSet is an instance member on one of the DataAdapter classes (SqlDataAdapter, OdbcDataAdapter, etc). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Euphoric "I have a Contacts table for each person in a Persons table" - What he said is perfectly fine, his is an objected-oriented perspective on things.  So there's impedance mismatch, he think in terms of objects, yet the component(ADO.NET) he is using just support relational look at things, in fact almost raw, almost flat. He should be using an ORM so he can work in terms of objects

Comment: @MichaelBuen That doesn't excuse him from not having elementary knowledge how SQL works.

Comment: @Euphoric sorry for my lack of db knowledge. All I've read about is the basic concepts and queries. As MB said I'm an OO thinker, just stumbling around in the dark until I find myself a working db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euphoric is correct in the comments, if a bit rude.  There's no way you should have a separate contacts table for each person.  The normal way would be to have a single *Contacts* table and put a foreign key linking back to the *Persons* table.  That way you could accomplish everything in a single query and wouldn't have to worry about querying tables unknown until runtime.

As far as why the code you listed isn't working, your suspicion is basically correct: it's not connected to any database.  You're creating a new empty table and attempting to query it.  To get this to work you would need to use **SqlConnection** to connect to the database, then use **SqlDataAdapter** and its **Fill** method to populate your **DataTable**.  (But again, please don't do this if possible, read up on SQL foreign keys.)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're not really using LINQ to query your database.

But most importantly, you should have only 1 `Contacts` table in your database with a relationship to `Persons` table.

Get Microsoft sample Northwind database (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23654) and learn more about database schema design.